# Replace numeric value with another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span in my HTML as follows, which I am assigning the text from code behind:

```
<span id="NewL1" visible="false"
    runat="server"><span runat="server" id="NewL"></span></span>
```

The text would be something like : "you have 3 notifications."

I want to change the numeric value in jQuery. I have tried this but nothing happens:

```
var notification = $("#NewL");
var numb = notification.text().match(/\d/g);
var finalTotalCount = parseInt(numb) - 1;
notification.text(notification.text().replace(numb, finalTotalCount ));
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't go this way. Instead of replacing, generate the whole string from scratch, then update the DOM: this way you can be more flexible [e.g. use singular when there is one notification only], and you don't mess with regexes for such a task.

Comment: When is your JS code running? Onload? Are you sure that by then the span will have content?

Comment: Your code is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/ykg62/

Comment: @moonwave99 i am doing this as for future changes one place needs to be changed :)

Comment: @Deleteman it runs on selecting a button

Comment: @LenielMacaferi thanks for that just noticed something my span is inside another span would that make difference(see my edit of html please)?

Comment: @Sam1 no difference, provided that they do not have the same id. Since you're getting the spam with id `newL` and it's unique it should be OK.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi just update jsfilddle with two spans and it is not working

Comment: @Sam1: It's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/ykg62/2/ I think it has to do with where you're inserting the text... :)

Comment: @LenielMacaferi sorry my bad, yes it works on jsfiddle

Comment: @Sam1 of course you'll be using a [template](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more), so you would just edit that if needed ^^

Comment: @Sam1: can you show us your code behind code where you assign the text value to the span tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have this HTML code:

```
<span id="NewL1" visible="false" runat="server">
    <span runat="server" id="NewL">you have 3 notifications</span>
</span>
```

Then, your current JavaScript code just works provided that your dynamic text `you have 3 notifications` is being inserted in the right place, that is, within the inner `span`.

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/ykg62/2/

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
var finalTotalCount = parseInt(numb) - 1;
```

With:

```
var finalTotalCount = parseInt(numb[0]) - 1;
```

`.match(/\d/g)` returns an array of strings that match the regex. You'll want to get the first result of that array, assuming you only have 1 number in your text.

**Edit**

Apparently, `parseInt` uses the first element in the array, if a array is provided. So, technically, my suggestion isn't necessary.

Comment: Hi, I only have one number in the string. I can see the finalTotalCount decreasing but dont see it being replaced.

Comment: @Deleteman: Hm, I see. Apparently, `parseInt` uses the first element in the array, if a array is provided. Still, best practices, right?

Sam1: your code appears to work. Did you copy all your relevant code to the question?

Comment: @Cerbrus didnt include the span inside another span see my edit of html please

Comment: @Sam1: that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Deleteman +1 for suggestion...I think the first span is not visible or the fact that am assigning from code behind may be issue(although the text is there when the above jquery code runs)

Answer (score 1):

Modify you code like this and try again

```
var notification = $("#NewL");
var numb = notification.text().match(/\d/g)[0];
var finalTotalCount = parseInt(numb) - 1;
notification.text(notification.text().replace(numb, finalTotalCount ));
```

Also, in your code:

```
<span id="NewL1" visible="false" runat="server">
    <span runat="server" id="NewL"></span>
</span>
```

You have `span` inside a hidden `span`*(visible="false")*. So won't be able to see any changes done. You can simply put your code like this and try again:

```
<span runat="server" id="NewL"></span>
```